# Unity3D : Where to put external files?

Tags: unity, c#, file

I want my game to be user-translated friendly.I put .text file to Data folder from where strings will be read. What is Editor alternative for data folder ? Also i know compiler ignore some files, how i can tell compiler to include this one ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [StreamingAssets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html).

When you build your projects, all folders and files are packed, making it difficult, or even impossible, to edit.

All except one folder. The StreamingAsset folder. Retrieve its path with

```
 Application.streamingAssetsPath
```

This folder is not put in the package when you compiled, but stays next to it, letting anyone edit its content

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what i need. Thanks a lot, I didn't know about this.